# How to fetch total destination views column data from pinterest API?

Tags: c#, postman, pinterest, pinterest-api

I was automating something and trying to fetch pinterest report data. I want to fetch Destination views data, but current reporting endpoint of pinterest does not support Destination Views. Took the column mapping of destination views from network tab.

**Endpoint**:
[https://api.pinterest.com/v5/ad_accounts/{ad_account_id}/reports](https://api.pinterest.com/v5/ad_accounts/%7Bad_account_id%7D/reports).
**API Column Name**: Total_Destination_Views
**Console Name for the column**: Destination views

How to fetch the Destination views data?Any endpoint supports it?